# Como faço para pegar um valor de true ou false do banco de dados no Wordpress antes do loop

Tags: condição

Eu tenho um campo personalizado para exibir um slide que é um campo booleana!
Quero fazer uma condição antes do loop se o resultado for true exibir o slide se false escode o slide

quero que essa condição seja realiza antes do loop só que retorna sempre false alguém poderia me ajudar?